# Date becomes one (1) day behind after submitting model from Angular 6 to Web API

Tags: datetime, angular6, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a web application using **Angular 6 and PrimeNG** controls for Frontend development and **ASP.Net Web API and SQL Server** for Backend development.

In one of my forms, there are two PrimeNG Calender controls to save From date and End date into the database. After the form is submitted all the form fields are collected to populate an object/model and passed this model to the Web API. The object/model is populated in Angular 6 using Typescript code. Below is my frontend model in Typescript code:

```
export class MyPackage {
    public PackageId: number;
    public PackageUid: number;
    public PackageName: string;
    public PackageDesc: string;
    public ValidFrom: Date;
    public ValidTill: Date;
    public CreatedOn: Date;
}
```

Here is my object initialization process with Angular 6 and typescript:

```
let pakg = new MyPackage();
pakg.PackageName = this.packageAddForm.controls["packageName"].value;
pakg.PackageDesc = this.packageAddForm.controls["packageDesc"].value;
pakg.ValidFrom = this.packageAddForm.controls["dateFrom"].value;
pakg.ValidTill = this.packageAddForm.controls["dateEnd"].value;
```

Now the problem is when the model is passed to the Web API, **From Date and End Date values become 1 day less** which I don't know why. I have debugged my Angular 6 code and see that it passes the exact dates which I selected but when this model arrives in the Web API the dates become 1 day behind.

Can anyone describe, why this problem occurs and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A likely culprit is the time zone offset between the client and the server.

When JavaScript dates are sent via the Angular HTTP Client, the data is converted to a JSON string using the JSON.stingify() method. This [converts all dates into strings using ISO 8601 format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ
```

One confusing aspect of this format is the purpose of the letter Z at the end, which stands for Zulu, or Zero UTC timezone offset.

When the date is converted to this string, the numerical time value is actually modified to reflect no timezone offset, instead of the timezone offset of the client. This is to normalize actual time in case the server is in a different timezone.

The important thing is to make sure the Web API is set up to interpret this string value representation of the time based on the zero UTC offset.

Comment: Can you please let me know how i can configure API call so that date is not formatted.

Comment: Before sending the JSON data to the server (via the HTTP request), you could convert the date to a simple string, like 'MM/DD/yy'. Working with JavaScript dates can be tricky, though. I'd recommend looking into using moment.js for this task.

Comment: Example: `const dateStr = (date.getMonth()+1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();`

Answer (score 4):

angular client changes payload date format on HTTP Request. I solved my problem adding this to my module providers :

```
{ provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'en-GB' }, /* optional */
{ provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
```

and import them like this :

```
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from "@angular/material/core";
```

and finally add this part to your modules and auto import

```
import: [MatDatepickerModule,MatMomentDateModule]
```

and your problem is solved too , hopefully :)

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this issue you need to convert date into "MM/DD/YYYY" format,

Follow the below steps in your .ts file in  Angular Application,

1) Import DatePipe like

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
```

2) Add the below in constructor

```
private datePipe: DatePipe
```

3) Convert your date using transform,

```
this.StartDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.todayDate, 'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

Note: The date variable should be any type.

Comment: It will not work as Date cannot be converted to string. It will throw error

Answer (score 2):

My time zone is GMT +6:00 (Bangladesh Time).
In same situation  my problem solved  by using moment format like this.

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ');
```

**Using Inside Angular:**

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';

    currentDate : any = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ');
    
    ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.currentDate);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
2022-03-22T12:31:47+06:00
```

---

**To install moment.js via npm, use:**

```
npm install moment --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a string in format 'DD/MM/YYY', and I had to convert it to Date type before sending it to WebApi server.
So I converted it to UTC date using moment.js library.

Angular send with Date type request field.
WebApi (c#) got DateTyme type request field.
Day-reduced problem is solved :)

Here is my code for the string "26/01/2005":

```
moment.utc("26/01/2005", "DD/MM/YYYY").toDate()
```

To install moment.js via npm, use:

```
npm install moment --save
```

mor details about moment.js you can find in https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

I know I am too late, but still it might be helpful for others, If you don't want to change the type of date variable to string, simply you can use below code. I had the same issue, i used below code and its working perfectly fine...

```
 this.pakg.ValidFrom = new Date(Date.UTC(this.pakg.ValidFrom.getFullYear(), this.pakg.ValidFrom.getMonth(), this.pakg.ValidFrom.getDate()));
 this.pakg.ValidTill = new Date(Date.UTC(this.pakg.ValidTill.getFullYear(), this.pakg.ValidTill.getMonth(), this.pakg.ValidTill.getDate()));
```

here you have to apply above code before hitting API's...